# VerticalCardPager not taking full width

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When using the `VerticalCardPager` on a page on its own, it works with no problems.

However, when using it beneath other widgets, the cards shrink in size. I have tried wrapping within a SingleChildScrollView to extend the page but this does not work with the Expanded/Flexible widget.

[image]

### HomeScreen

```dart
import 'package:club2_app/widgets/vertical_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../widgets/news_card.dart';
import '../constants.dart';
import '../widgets/app_bar.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    "News",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: kPrimaryLightColor,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ), // 'News'
            NewsCard(),
            Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Posts',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: kPrimaryLightColor,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ), // 'Posts'
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                width: double.infinity,
                child: VerticalCard(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### VerticalCardWidget

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vertical_card_pager/vertical_card_pager.dart';

class VerticalCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VerticalCardState createState() => _VerticalCardState();
}

final List<String> titles = [
  "How to Manage Injuries",
  "Is Football Getting Faster?",
  "Improving Match Fitness",
  "Expected Goals: The Over and Under Achievers",
];

final List<Widget> images = [
  Hero(
    tag: "News 1",
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Image.asset(
          "assets/images/Mbappe.jpeg",
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  Hero(
    tag: "News 2",
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      child: Image.asset(
        "assets/images/Mbappe.jpeg",
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  Hero(
    tag: "News 3",
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      child: Image.asset(
        "assets/images/Mbappe.jpeg",
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  Hero(
    tag: "News 4",
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      child: Image.asset(
        "assets/images/Mbappe.jpeg",
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  ),
];

class _VerticalCardState extends State<VerticalCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return VerticalCardPager(
      titles: titles,
      images: images,
      onPageChanged: (page) {
        // print(page);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it is a limitation of the `VerticalCardPager`.

The `width` and `height` of the cards inside a `VerticalCardPager` are defined based on the `maxHeight` of the Parent Widget:

```dart
double getWidth(maxHeight, i) {
  double cardMaxWidth = maxHeight / 2;
  return cardMaxWidth - 60 * (i - 2).abs();
}

double getHeight(maxHeight, i) {
  double cardMaxHeight = maxHeight / 2;
  if (i == 2) {
    return cardMaxHeight;
  } else if (i == 0 || i == 4) {
    return cardMaxHeight - cardMaxHeight * (4 / 5) - 10;
  } else
    return cardMaxHeight - cardMaxHeight * (4 / 5);
  }
}
```

For `i == 2`, the middle Card, the `width` and `height` are both equal to `maxHeight / 2`.

So, if you want the Cards to have a different aspect ratio and fill the width of the screen, you will have to modify the code of the `VerticalCardPager`.

---

However, if you want to keep the same aspect ratio and expand out of the screen. You can use a `SingleChildScrollView` as you mentioned. Here you go:

```dart
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Vertical Pager')),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              [...]
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: VerticalCard(),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, the scrolling behavior might be a little bit chaotic, or even impossible on some devices.

Comment: I thought so, been trying to find a work around but had the same issues as the one you offered as it does not look as clean - if you have a page just dedicated to the widget then there are no problems! Thanks - I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap Your column into container and set its width to "double.infinity"